# how to extract a variable inside a function and put in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have these functions below:

```
    function func1(){
        var var1 = $('.someclass_a').val();
        var var2 = var1 * some_number1;
        var var3 = var2 * some_number2;
        $('.someclass1').html(var2);
        $('.someclass2').html(var3);
    }

    function func2(){
        var var1 = $('.someclass_b').val();
        var var2 = var1 * some_number1;
        var var3 = var2 * some_number2;
        $('.someclass3').html(var2);
        $('.someclass4').html(var3);
    }
```

how do I extract both var2 and var3 on all the functions above so that I can add them in another function below:

```
    function func3(){
        var total1 = func1_var2 + func2_var2;
        var total2 = func1_var3 + func2_var3;
        $('.someclass5').html(total1);
        $('.someclass6').html(total2);
    }
```

i was thinking of putting them in an array but I dunno how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables outside the function and give them different names. Then inside the functions you can access and change them. And the last function will work just fine.

Just remember to use different names

Answer (score 1):

Return an object and invoke the functions?

```
 function func1(){
    var var1 = $('.someclass_a').val();
    var var2 = var1 * some_number1;
    var var3 = var2 * some_number2;
    $('.someclass1').html(var2);
    $('.someclass2').html(var3);
    return {var2:var2,var3:var3}; //return object here
}

function func2(){
    var var1 = $('.someclass_b').val();
    var var2 = var1 * some_number1;
    var var3 = var2 * some_number2;
    $('.someclass3').html(var2);
    $('.someclass4').html(var3);
    return {var2:var2,var3:var3}; //return object here
}

 function func3(){
    var func1Ob = func1(), func2Ob = func2(), total1 , total2; //invoke the funcs
    total1 = func1Ob.var2 + func2Ob.var2; //get the values from obj returned.
    total2 = func1Ob.var3 + func2Ob.var3;
    $('.someclass5').html(total1);
    $('.someclass6').html(total2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've partially replied to your own question :

```
var func1_var2, func1_var3, func2_var2, func2_var3;

function func1(){
    var var1 = $('.someclass_a').val();
    var var2 = func1_var2 = var1 * some_number1;
    var var3 = func1_var3 = var2 * some_number2;
    $('.someclass1').html(var2);
    $('.someclass2').html(var3);
}

function func2(){
    var var1 = $('.someclass_b').val();
    var var2 = func2_var2 = var1 * some_number1;
    var var3 = func2_var3 = var2 * some_number2;
    $('.someclass3').html(var2);
    $('.someclass4').html(var3);
}
```

Not more than Maxim said.