# How do you extract a variable inside a function of an object?

Tags: javascript

I just started coding a week ago and Im a bit stuck in coding challenge from a class im taking from Udemy. Can anyone please summarize and help me understand how I can extract a variable generated from a for loop inside a function of an object? I was hoping to extract the tips inside the calcTips function. But everything I tried is an error. Thank you in advance!

```js
var markFamily = {
  bills: [77, 375, 110, 45],
  calcTips: function() {
    var tips = [];
    var finalBill = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = this.bills.length; i < len; i++) {
      var percentage;
      if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
        percentage = .2;
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] < 300) {
        percentage = .15;
      } else {
        percentage = .25;
      }
      tips.push(this.bills[i] * percentage);
      finalBill.push(tips[i] + this.bills[i]);
    }
    console.log(tips);
    console.log(finalBill);
  }
}

markFamily.calcTips();
```

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Do you want the value of `tips` to be returned?

Comment: you just need to `return finalBill` at the end of the `calcTips` function. And then you probably want a `var result = ...` at the start of the final line so that you can assign that return value to a variable. (You can of course use whichever variable name is most appropriate for you.) Try looking up functions and return values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract a variable inside a function and put in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468535/how-to-extract-a-variable-inside-a-function-and-put-in-another-function)

Comment: [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)